# Can Firefox's offline mode be disabled?

Tags: firefox

My wifi often cuts out. Turning wifi on and off seems to help, but Firefox often puts itself into offline mode. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this in your address bar;

```
about:config
```

Then enter this in "filter"

```
network.manage-offline-status
```

Change it to "false"

Other versions of firefox may have to set this to "true";

```
toolkit.networkmanager.disable
```

Or this to "false"

```
browser.offline-apps.notify
```

If that doesn't work, there's [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13152/) extension to block offline mode.

Comment: I thought that it worked at first, but it doesn't seem to be working. Firefox still goes into Offline mode sometimes

Comment: I updated my answer with some other suggestions. Good luck!

Comment: According to the addon, the setting is: network.manage-offline-status in Firefox 3.6 or above

Comment: Ty. Updated my answer. Amazing how many times that setting got renamed :\